Ways to store data for a request body?
I am working on a solution to map outputs of a pipeline to an endpoint.
The endpoint can be any endpoint, as the out of the pipeline can be anything and is fully customizable.
Basically, I want to be able to dynamically call any restful post-endpoint.
I have noticed that I cannot request for the requirements of a request body for a POST endpoint. So I want the user to input the request body manually so I can perform type checking on the output of the pipeline.
I want to store the submitted data in a SQL database, but how would I store such data?
Should I store it in a simple table like this:
(I don't know how to clearly display my ideas of a table so I'll use lucid charts to represent them)

Where JSON would be similar to what Pydantic outputs when converting a schema to JSON. (Unless there is something better? Im using python and already making use of Pydatic for it's schema's. I thought it would be a consistent solution)
Or should I store each field seperately so I can have more consistent data to work with?

The FieldTypes table could also be a simple Enum in the codebase instead of a table.
I'm tempted to use my first suggestion as that one is easier to implement, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to do so. Are there better ways to store data for a request body?

You're going to try and stored semi-structured data inside a structured database and you have no idea what the format may be? I think you need to look elsewhere and use a document-oriented database like NoSQL with document store. Using a structured database here will give you no advantages what so ever and only hinder your development and query potential. If you have no choice, then I suggest your first option.
